# missing predictor data model in JAGS

Tags: r, missing-data, bayesian, jags

I'm trying to program the simplest missing data model in JAGS.
One predictor (with a few missing data points) and one outcome variable.
I know the example is not the most useful or realistic, but it's helping me work out the model kinks before I go on to a more complicated missing predictor data scenario.

The model and data are below, but here's the compile error:

```
  Error in jags.model("MISSING_model.txt", data = dataList, inits = initsList, : 
    RUNTIME ERROR:
  Unable to resolve the following parameters:
  x[3] (line 5)
  x[4] (line 5)
  x[7] (line 5)
  x[13] (line 5)
  x[18] (line 5)
  x[20] (line 5)
  Either supply values for these nodes with the data
  or define them on the left hand side of a relation.
```

These are the missing data points; I do define them below so I'm not sure where the mistake is.

the code:

```
# DEFINING THE DATA:
myData <-  matrix (
           c(64.0, 62.3,   NA,   NA, 64.8, 57.5,   NA, 70.2, 63.9, 71.1, 
             66.5, 68.1,   NA, 75.1, 64.6, 69.2, 68.1,   NA, 63.2,   NA, 
             64.1, 71.5, 76.0, 69.7, 73.3, 61.7, 66.4, 65.7, 68.3, 66.9,
            136.4,215.1,173.6,117.3,123.3, 96.5,178.3,191.1,158.0,193.9, 
            127.1,147.9,119.0,204.4,143.4,124.4,140.9,164.7,139.8,110.2, 
            134.1,193.6,180.0,155.0,188.2,187.4,139.2,147.9,178.6,111.1) ,
             nrow=30  )
colnames(myData) <- c("height","weight")
myData <- as.data.frame(myData)
```

I define a missing data index here:

```
# this index will help setup priors and let us look at posterior values for missing x's
  mIdx <- ifelse( is.na(myData$height) , 1 , 0)
  mIdx <- sapply( 1:length(mIdx), 
                  function(n) mIdx[n]*sum(mIdx[1:n]))
    # result: mIdx = 
      #              0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 
      #              0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 6, 
      #              0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

# add missing index to myData
  myData$mIdx <- mIdx
```

here's the data prep section

```
# DATA PREP:
  y = myData[,"weight"]
  x = myData[,"height"]
  meanY = mean(y,na.rm=TRUE) 
  meanX = mean(x,na.rm=TRUE) 
  sdY = sd(y,na.rm=TRUE)     
  sdX = sd(x,na.rm=TRUE)
  mIdx = myData[,"mIdx"]
  Ntotal = length(y)
# Specify the data list for JAGS
    dataList = list(
    x = x ,
    y = y ,
    mIdx = mIdx , 
    meanY = meanY ,
    meanX = meanX ,
    sdY = sdY ,
    sdX = sdX ,
    Ntotal = Ntotal
)
```

here's the model

```
# THE MODEL
# Standardize the data:
data {
  for ( i in 1:Ntotal ) {
      zx[i] <- ifelse ( mIdx[i]==0, ( x[i] - meanX ) / sdX , x[i] ) # skips NA's
      zy[i] <- ( y[i] - meanY ) / sdY
    }
}
# Specify the model for standardized data:
model {
  for ( i in 1:Ntotal ) {
    zy[i] ~ dt( zbeta0 + zbeta1 * zx[i] , 1/zsigma^2 , nu )
  }
# prior for imputing missing zx's
  zx ~ dnorm( 0 , 1 )
# Priors vague on standardized scale:
  zbeta0 ~ dnorm( 0 , 1/(10)^2 )  
  zbeta1 ~ dnorm( 0 , 1/(10)^2 )
  zsigma ~ dunif( 1.0E-3 , 1.0E+3 )
  nu ~ dexp(1/30.0)
# Transform back to original scale:
  beta1 <- zbeta1 * ysd / xsd  
  beta0 <- zbeta0 * ysd  + ym - zbeta1 * xm * ysd / xsd 
  sigma <- zsigma * ysd
  x <- zx*sdX + meanX
}
```

and finally the initial values for the MCMC chains:

```
# INITIALIZE VALUES
 # values hardcoded for simplicity
 beta0 = 0   ;  zbeta0 = 0
 beta1 = 3.6 ;  zbeta1 = 0.5
 sigma = 30  ;  zsigma = 1
 nu = 30
# initial values for missing x data:
  xInit = rep( NA , length(x) )
  xInit[3] <- 68 ; xInit[4]<- 64 ; xInit[7] <- 68
  xInit[13] <- 64 ; xInit[18] <- 68 ; xInit[20] <- 64
initsList = list( beta0=beta0 ,  beta1=beta1 , zbeta0=zbeta0 , zbeta1=zbeta1 , 
                zsigma=zsigma , sigma=sigma, nu = nu , x=xInit )
```

and the jags call:

```
jagsModel = jags.model( "MISSING_model.txt" , data=dataList , inits=initsList , 
                      n.chains=nChains , n.adapt=adaptSteps )
```

The error seems to be from improperly setting up the prior for the missing data:

```
# imputed prior for missing zx's
  zx ~ dnorm( 0 , 1 )
```

I read that jags will automatically toggle between the data and the prior when there are NA's present, but I'm not sure where my code goes wrong for the zx's.

Thanks for your tips and help.

Answer (score 0):

The code had several errors.  In particular, some values were misnamed in the model (ysd instead of sdY, for example) and initial values were given to non-stochartic variables (beta0, beta1 and sigma).

But two problems were key issues for the imputation:

First, the prior for imputing has to be done for each position of the vector. Instead of

```
# prior for imputing missing zx's
zx ~ dnorm( 0 , 1 )
```

one should use

```
# prior for imputing missing zx's
for (i in 1:Ntotal){
  zx[i] ~ dnorm( 0 , 1 )
}
```

And secondly, apparently JAGS is not happy to compute values with NA's in the `data` environment.  An easy solution is to create these standardized variables in `R`, outside the `JAGS` model.

A fully reproducible code is presented here

```
# DEFINING THE DATA:
myData <-  matrix (
  c(64.0, 62.3,   NA,   NA, 64.8, 57.5,   NA, 70.2, 63.9, 71.1, 
    66.5, 68.1,   NA, 75.1, 64.6, 69.2, 68.1,   NA, 63.2,   NA, 
    64.1, 71.5, 76.0, 69.7, 73.3, 61.7, 66.4, 65.7, 68.3, 66.9,
    136.4,215.1,173.6,117.3,123.3, 96.5,178.3,191.1,158.0,193.9, 
    127.1,147.9,119.0,204.4,143.4,124.4,140.9,164.7,139.8,110.2, 
    134.1,193.6,180.0,155.0,188.2,187.4,139.2,147.9,178.6,111.1) ,
  nrow=30  )
colnames(myData) <- c("height","weight")
myData <- as.data.frame(myData)



# this index will help setup priors and let us look at posterior values for missing x's
mIdx <- ifelse( is.na(myData$height) , 1 , 0)
mIdx <- sapply( 1:length(mIdx), 
                function(n) mIdx[n]*sum(mIdx[1:n]))
# result: mIdx = 
#              0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 
#              0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 6, 
#              0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

# add missing index to myData
myData$mIdx <- mIdx



# DATA PREP:
y = myData[,"weight"]
x = myData[,"height"]
meanY = mean(y,na.rm=TRUE) 
meanX = mean(x,na.rm=TRUE) 
sdY = sd(y,na.rm=TRUE)     
sdX = sd(x,na.rm=TRUE)
Ntotal = length(y)
zx <- zy <- NULL
for ( i in 1:Ntotal ) {
  zx[i] <- ifelse ( mIdx[i]==0, ( x[i] - meanX ) / sdX , x[i] ) # skips NA's
  zy[i] <- ( y[i] - meanY ) / sdY
}
# Specify the data list for JAGS
dataList = list(
  zx = zx ,
  zy = zy ,
  meanY = meanY ,
  meanX = meanX ,
  sdY = sdY ,
  sdX = sdX ,
  Ntotal = Ntotal
)



# THE MODEL

model_string <- "
# Specify the model for standardized data:
model {
  for ( i in 1:Ntotal ) {
    zy[i] ~ dt( zbeta0 + zbeta1 * zx[i] , 1/zsigma^2 , nu )
  }
  # prior for imputing missing zx's
  for (i in 1:Ntotal){
    zx[i] ~ dnorm( 0 , 1 )
    # Estimated covariates
    ximp[i] <- zx[i]*sdX + meanX
  }
  # Priors vague on standardized scale:
  zbeta0 ~ dnorm( 0 , 1/(10)^2 )  
  zbeta1 ~ dnorm( 0 , 1/(10)^2 )
  zsigma ~ dunif( 1.0E-3 , 1.0E+3 )
  nu ~ dexp(1/30.0)
  # Transform back to original scale:
  beta1 <- zbeta1 * sdY / sdX  
  beta0 <- zbeta0 * sdY  + meanY - zbeta1 * meanX * sdY / sdX 
  sigma <- zsigma * sdY
}
"

# INITIALIZE VALUES
# values hardcoded for simplicity
zbeta0 = 0
zbeta1 = 0.5
zsigma = 1
nu = 30
# initial values for missing x data:
xInit = rep( NA , length(x) )
xInit[3] <- 68 ; xInit[4]<- 64 ; xInit[7] <- 68
xInit[13] <- 64 ; xInit[18] <- 68 ; xInit[20] <- 64
initsList = list( zbeta0=zbeta0 , zbeta1=zbeta1 , 
                  zsigma=zsigma , nu = nu , x=xInit )

nChains=2

library(rjags)
jagsModel = jags.model( textConnection(model_string) , data=dataList , inits=initsList , 
                        n.chains=nChains , n.adapt=adaptSteps )

update(jagsModel,5000)

# Running the model
samp=coda.samples(jagsModel, variable.names=c("beta0", "beta1", "sigma", "nu", "ximp"), 
                  n.iter=2000)

plot(samp)
```